# How to make image-dired work on remote files?

Tags: dired, tramp, image-dired

I've tried `ssh`and `scp` for tramp's method (both work for tramp), yet image-dired thumbnail creation fails

```
Thumb could not be created for /scp:raspi:/media/pi/91D4-7E58//IMG_1.JPG: exited abnormally with code 1
```

Do I need to setup filesharing e.g. `nfs` or is there something else I could try before?

Both, tramp and image-dired work fine on local files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image-dired` uses `start-process` and `call-process`. This means, it cannot handle remote files.

If you want support for remote files, you might write an Emacs bug report.